# Not able to consume the Spring MVC Rest service from stand alone html file

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have created the REST Service using Spring MVC (`@RestController` ) which is used to consume Json request and expose the Json response and I placed the  `.html` file  inside  the `web-app` folder . in that `html` file using `jquery+Ajax` i am able consuming the REST Service. it is working fine.  ( I have given the relative path).

How can I access the `REST` service from outside of the application ? or how i will access my `REST` service using Absolute path ?

Note : I am using `Spring boot`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to request the absolute path http://host:port/rest_service_path.

You also can access and test your rest services with Postman(A chrome extension).

Comment: yes correct, i am trying with absolute path but spring boot show "no handler method found for this url" error message in the console.

Comment: I am using Mozilla REST Client plugin for testing the REST service.